# Does anyone know of a fast bus for local messaging between applications on the same machine?

Tags: .net, messaging, bus

I'm looking for a pub/sub mechanism that can be used by .NET applications running on the same machine (a mixture of different app domains and processes).  I'd really rather avoid having to run a separate service or anything that requires too much configuration.  Obviously I'd like to keep the memory and cpu load to a minimum too.

Specifically I want to broadcast high volumes of small messages to subscribers on the same host.  So I want a bus (e.g. MSMQ or NServiceBus) - but I don't want the overhead of full network support (it only needs local named pipes) or the cost and complexity of an enterprise bus.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements a bit:  1. do you need durable/persistent messages  2. do you need transactional processing (sending and receiving)  3. how many messages do you want to handle

Comment: It doesn't need to be durable (in the sense that it can all be in memory - if a process fails then it'll never receive the message), but it does need to be transactional (ie. a process should be confident that if it has posted a message it should be received by all running subscribers)

Comment: Oh, and a max of around 10 messages/second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named pipes is the fastest way to do local process interaction.

Reference:
[`NamedPipeServerStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx)
[`NamedPipeClientStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx)
[`Choosing a transport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)

Important reading:
[Don't get in a deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx)

Comment: WCF doesn't provide a simple pub/sub messaging implementation though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send a signal from one process to other that some portion of work is done, the most lightweight solution could be a [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that configured properly, MSMQ + NServiceBus would be able to achieve your desired throughput on a single machine.  There is an [Express] attribute that will cause your messages to not be written to disk.  If performance is adequate, you are much better off using a high-level framework like this than rolling your own.

Comment: This approach is probably the most conventional, but it is quite heavywight for a desktop deployment.  I was really hoping for something much simpler that could be set up on an ad-hoc basis by a running application.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that this was a desktop app.  Maybe then using WCF with the named pipe binding would do the trick for you?  That would hide at least some of the mess and is fully appropriate for a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mailslots
Memory Mapped files
Named Pipes
LPC
```

All on Windows

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my definitive solution, but one solution that has come up is [0MQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/) which offers a reliable pub/sub mode and has relatively low requirements for configuration and infrastructure.  The downside is that it is relatively low level (the .NET API is a wrapper around the native C code) - so I will need to implement all the serialisation and so on.

I'll post back when I've had time to experiment and come to a conclusion.

Comment: You could try implementing an 0MQ transport for NServiceBus, that way you'd get all the niceties of NSB while ditching MSMQ.